# Maximum number of triangles no two of which have a common edge

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

For $n\in N_+$, define $f(n)$ to be the maximum number of triangles in a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, taken over all $n$-vertex graphs having the property where no two triangles have a common edge.

Do we have some good estimates for $f(n)$?

By triangle removal lemma, we can prove for any $\varepsilon>0$, while $n$ is large, we have $f(n)<\varepsilon n^2$.

(Intuitively, for a regular partition of $G$, if any triangle contributes an edge to a "low density part" (or some ignored part), then the "low density part" can not suffer so much edge. So there's some triangle which every edge contained in a "high density part", and then we'll get $cn^3$ triangles, which can't independent in edge.)

If we can prove that $f(n)<\frac{\varepsilon n^2}{ln\ n}$ for large $n$, then we can prove that there exists infinitely many triples of primes which forms an arithmetic sequence, in a combinatorial way.

Comment: There is of course the trivial lower bound $f(n)\gt cn^{3/2}$ from the fact that $f\left(\binom n2\right)\ge\binom n3$ but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: I think this is a somewhat simpler triangle removal argument: Since every edge is in at most one triangle, there are $O(n^2)$ triangles, so by the triangle removal lemma we can destroy them all by removing $o(n^2)$ edges. So actually there were $o(n^2)$ triangles.

Comment: The best known constructions with respect to the triangle removal lemma (so called Behrend graphs) show that $f(n)\ge \frac{n^2}{\exp(\sqrt{\log n})}$.

Comment: The connection between the triangle removal lemma and Roth's theorem was noticed long time ago, see this survey http://math.mit.edu/~fox/paper-removalsurvey.pdf for the history and some recent results.

Comment: If I understand the question then it is the same as the [maximum number of monotone, linear X3SAT clauses for $n$ variables](https://oeis.org/A001839).

Comment: @Russell Easterly no, sometimes you can take many triangle which no two of them have a common edge, but their edges may create another bad triangle.

Comment: What if graph $G$ is a planar graph? Maybe $f(n)<\varepsilon n, \varepsilon<1 $.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the values of $f(n)$ for $n\in \{1,\dots,15\}$ are $$0,0,1,1,2,2,3,4,6,6,7,9,10,12,15,$$ which does not seem to be in the OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question "do we have some good estimates for $f(n)$?" is no. Or at least, the situation is the same as that for triangle removal itself. The assertion that $f(n) = o(n^2)$ is normally called the Ruzsa--Szemeredi theorem: see for instance footnote 1 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3487. I think that people who think about this stuff generally think of Ruzsa--Szemeredi and triangle removal as morally (but not quite exactly) equivalent.